# ADC instruction in asm

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, carryflag

In the following code,

```
MOV AL,NUMBER1
ADD AL,NUMBER2
MOV AH, 00H
ADC AH, 00H
```

what are lines 3 and 4 for? What do they do?

Also, why does the code clear AH? (I assume because AL's "ADD" operation may produce carry.)

Comment: That's pretty inefficient, unless you need it to run on pre-386.  The last two instructions can be replaced with `setc ah`.  It could also have done `movzx eax, byte NUMBER1` / `movzx ecx, byte NUMBER2` / `add eax, ecx`to produce a 9-bit sum in AX, but that requires a scratch register to hold the zero-extended NUMBER2.  (An 8086-compatible version of that could use `xor ax,ax` / `mov al, NUMBER1` or something.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To figure this out, start by looking up what each instruction does:

- `MOV  AH, 00H`

  This [`MOV` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html) will set the `AH` register to 0 *without* affecting flags.
- `ADC  AH, 00H`

  This [`ADC` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_4.html) will add the source operand (0), the carry flag (CF), and the destination operand (`AH`), storing the result in the destination operand (`AH`).

  Symbolically, then, it does: `AH = AH + 0 + CF`

  Remember that the `MOV` did not affect the flags, so the value of CF that is used by the `ADC` instruction is whatever was set previously by the [`ADD` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_5.html) (in line 2).

  Also, `AH` is 0 at this point, so this is really just: `AH = CF`.

And now you know what the code does:

1. It moves `NUMBER1` into the `AL` register: `AL = NUMBER1`
2. It adds `NUMBER2` to the `AL` register: `AL = NUMBER1 + NUMBER2`
3. It clears `AH`: `AH = 0`
4. It sets `AH` equal to CF, as set by the addition of `NUMBER1` and `NUMBER2`. Thus, `AH` will be 1 if the addition required a carry, or 0 otherwise. (`AH = CF`)

As for the *purpose* of this code, it clearly performs a 16-bit addition of two 8-bit numbers. In a pseudo-C, it would basically be:

```
BYTE NUMBER1;
BYTE NUMBER2;
WORD RESULT = (WORD)NUMBER1 + (WORD)NUMBER2;
```

where the BYTE-sized inputs are extended to WORDs and added together. Why do this? Well, to handle overflow. If you add together two 8-bit values, the result may be larger than will fit in 8 bits.

The real trick to understanding this may be that the `AL` and `AH` registers are the lower and upper bits, respectively, of the `AX` registers. So immediately after these instructions, you may see `AX` being used. This contains the 16-bit *result* of the addition of `NUMBER1` and `NUMBER2`.

Comment: It seems that the *purpose* only applied to unsigned addition only.