# Could someone please explain what this inline #define assembly is doing?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, turbo-c, carryflag

I'm an occasional C programmer. I've come across this bit of inline assembly code in a Turbo C program

```
#define ADC(dst,src)    { asm MOV AX, dst;  asm ADD AX, src;  \
              asm ADC AX, 0;    asm MOV dst, AX; }
```

dst and src are both unsigned 16-bit integers.

It won't compile in GNU C++. Could someone please explain what it's doing? TIA!

Comment: Nothing that makes obvious sense ... it's adding the carry back to the result for whatever reason. Something like  `dst += src; if (dst < src) dst++;`

Comment: Am I right in thinking it would be something like this?

    AX= dst+ src;
    if((long)dst + (long)src > 0xffff)
       AX++;
    dst= AX;

Comment: I don't think gcc accepts that syntax for inline assembly. Also did you actually mean to write `GNU C++` or rather `GNU C`?

Comment: Yes you could make something along those lines too.

Comment: I'm using GNU c++ but it's being compiled as c

Comment: Inline assembly syntax is compiler specific because it is _not C_, so not defined by the language.  Also being a "occasional C programmer" is irrelevant, because again, this is _not C_.   Moreover Turbo C is an antique 16 bit compiler, so the assembler here is 16bit x86, which the 32 or 64 bit GCC will reject.

Comment: @Clifford note that all these assembler instructions can be assembled for 32 and 64- bit mode though

Comment: We see here why I suggest people [not use inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).  (Among other things) it presents challenges (exacerbated by the lack of comments) to people who come along later to maintain it.  "Occasional C programmers" are relatively common.  Asm programmers?  Not so much.  Since obviously this is someone else's code, I'm not blaming you.  But as NPE shows, it wasn't necessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Got the software going so am a happy man.

Comment: @Clifford An experienced C programmer would have been sure it wasn't C and known to look elsewhere.  An occasional C programmer very well might not.  Combine that with an awful lot of programmers these days not knowing assembly and this could be very cryptic.

Comment: Same as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540078/adc-instruction-in-asm/44540326#44540326), except with 16-bit operands/values, instead of 8-bit.

Answer (score 13):

The first two instructions add `dst` and `src` together, storing the result in the accumulator.  The third instruction computes what's sometimes called the "end-around carry" and the fourth stores the result in `dst`.

The following is an equivalent C implementation:

```
int32_t sum = dst + (int32_t)src;
dst = (int16_t)((sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16));
```

Wikipedia [talks about end-around carry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Ones'_complement) in its coverage of ones' complement:

> To add two numbers represented in this system, one does a conventional binary addition, but it is then necessary to do an **end-around carry**: that is, add any resulting carry back into the resulting sum.

End-around carry is used, for example, when calculating IPv4 checksums.

Comment: My assembler is quite rusty but my first thought on looking at the code was it was used in CRCs or the like.

Answer (score 7):

A literal translation of this code to GNU C inline assembly is:

```
static inline short ADC(short dst, short src)
{
     asm ("add %1, %0; adc $0, %0" : "+r"(dst) : "rmi"(src));

     return (dst);
}
```

But the version provided by NPE should be a bit more portable.